# sql compute time differ duration and skip rows value equal null

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm new to sql ,I use pandas a lot ,but my boss asks me to use sql replace lots of pandas code.

I have a table my_table:

```
case_id    first_created  last_paid       submitted_time
   3456    2021-01-27     2021-01-29      2021-01-26 21:34:36.566023+00:00
   7891    2021-08-02     2021-09-16      2022-10-26 19:49:14.135585+00:00
   1245    2021-09-13     None            2022-10-31 02:03:59.620348+00:00
   9073    None           None            2021-09-12 10:25:30.845687+00:00
   6891    2021-08-03     2021-09-17      None
```

First I need create 2 variables:

```
create_duration = first_created-submitted_time
paid_duration= last_paid-submitted_time
```

And if submitted_time is none just ignore that row ,else if create_duration or paid_duration

is negative ,convert it to 0,the unit should be days.

The ideal output should something similliar :

```
case_id    first_created  last_paid       submitted_time               create_duration paid_duration
   3456    2021-01-27     2021-01-29      2021-01-26 21:34:36.566023+00:00     1                3
   7891    2021-08-02     2021-09-16      2022-10-26 19:49:14.135585+00:00     0                0
   1245    2021-09-13     None            2022-10-31 02:03:59.620348+00:00     0                null
   9073    None           None            2021-09-12 10:25:30.845687+00:00     null             null
   6891    2021-08-03     2021-09-17      null                                 null             null
```

My code:

```
select * from my_table
first_created-submitted_time as create_duration
last_paid-submitted_time as paid_duration
```

I have to say I'm too bad at sql,I have no idea how to continue,any friend can help ?

Comment: Not tested, but should get you close: `first_created-coalesce(submitted_time::date, first_create)`and `last_paid-coalesce(submitted_time::date last_paid)`.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver ,thank you very much for your reply ,after modifying ,it works,but the results are all integer,what should I do ,if I want to the result be a float with 1 digit number remain like 1.3 days or 0.5 days ?

Comment: 1) That is not what your expected output shows. You need to update that to show what you really want. 2)To get decimal days e.g. 1.3 is going to require a function that converts hours into decimal equivalents.  Would something like `1 day 7 hours` work?

Comment: Hi I think your answer for this question works ,at the same time I opened a anther related question here ,can you help me ,thanks!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365945/sql-compute-time-differ-duration-and-leave-result-as-float